# Loading an assembly just once

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose I call `Assembly.LoadFile` with the name of a DLL many times. Is it loaded as many times as the call to the `LoadFile` method or just once, in a given process/app domain?

Consider this:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoSomething();
            DoSomeMoreStuff();

            // More of such method calls that each 
            // call Assembly.LoadFile()
        }

        static void DoSomething()
        {
            var asm = Assembly.LoadFile("SomeExternal.dll");

            // stuff happens...
        }

        static void DoSomeMoreStuff()
        {
            var asm = Assembly.LoadFile("SomeExternal.dll");

            // stuff happens...
        }
    }
```

If it loads the assembly as many times as the call, is there a way I may prevent that from happening?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish? Or is this question purely just for knowledge?

Comment: Assembly.LoadFile requires an absolute file path

Comment: 1 - In case of doubt, *don't* use LoadFile.  2 - If you think you need it, *don't* use LoadFile.  Repeat at step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx

Notice what it says in the remarks:

*LoadFile is useful in this limited scenario because LoadFrom cannot be used to load assemblies that have the same identities but different paths; it will load only the first such assembly.*

What I take away is that if the path is different it will load the assembly for each call. But if the path is the same then it will not.

But like @unholysampler said you can easily test this to confirm.

Comment: This is correct, and the reason why LoadFile only accepts a full path to its file argument (the call in the original poster's code will fail at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`LoadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) doesn't seem to say if it imports multiple times, so I would assume it does until told otherwise. The good news is that it is not hard to do this your self.

```
class Program
{
  private static Assembly _asm;

  private static Assembly getExternalDll()
  {
    if (_asm == null)
      _asm = Assembly.LoadFile("SomeExternal.dll");
    return _asm;
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    DoSomething();
    DoSomeMoreStuff();

    // More of such method calls that each 
    // call Assembly.LoadFile()
  }

  static void DoSomething()
  {
    var asm = getExternalDll();
    // stuff happens...
  }

  static void DoSomeMoreStuff()
  {
    var asm = getExternalDll();
    // stuff happens...
  }
}
```